# field value gets undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I Clear a event que in javascript?
when I have done one click event and then does another click event the input field gets the value undefined even when it has a value like "newfile.jpg"

I retrieves the values by doing somevariable = $('#cke_104_textInput').val();
but somevariable gets the value undefined.

here is the javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    function changeLink() {
        link = $('#cke_104_textInput').val();
        if (link == "") {}
        else {
            link = link.replace("_", "/");
            parts = link.split('.');
            explodeExtension = parts[parts.length - 1];
            link = link.replace("/download/", "/download/" + explodeExtension + "/");
            link = link.replace("." + explodeExtension, "");
            $('#cke_104_textInput').val('');
            $('#cke_104_textInput').val(link);
            clearInterval(changelink);
        }
    }

    function changePic() {
        link = $('#cke_103_textInput').val();
        if (link == "") {}
        else {
            link = link.replace("_", "/");
            parts = link.split('.');
            explodeExtension = parts[parts.length - 1];
            link = link.replace("/download/", "/show/" + explodeExtension + "/");
            link = link.replace("." + explodeExtension, "");
            $('#cke_103_textInput').val('');
            $('#cke_103_textInput').val(link);
            clearInterval(changepic);
        }
    }
    $('#cke_60').live('click', function (event) {
        changelink = setInterval(function () {
            changeLink()
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('#cke_64').live('click', function (event) {
        changepic = setInterval(function () {
            changePic()
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

In the code i try to rewrite the content of two input fields.
this has to be done because the files are not in the sites root they are outside of it, and to be able to show or download them on the site the urls need to be in a specific format.

Comment: This code is kind of a mess, especially the `changelink` and `changePic` variables -- they are called as functions and set as references to intervals, not going to work.. Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first line question, yes you can. Take a look at [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `link` as a global variable, which means it is clashing with itself.

Change `link = $('#cke_104_textInput').val();` to `var link = $('#cke_104_textInput').val();`.

Also as a side note, you have this code twice:

```
$('#cke_104_textInput').val('');
$('#cke_104_textInput').val(link);
```

which is redundant and inefficient.  You should remove the first line in both cases, because selecting an element (even via ID) is not a free operation.

Comment: Removed all dubbles, and added var before link but stil the same value of undefined